# How to replace part of a path using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sublimetext3

Hey stackoverflow community,  
I tried to set up a build system in Sublime Text 3  for my .html files in my xampp/htdocs dir.

Therefore I need to replace part of the filepath and add 
`"http://localhost/"`

 at the beginning and then call it in the browser. Feel free to post any suggestions.

What I found out so far from other threads:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
-- represtened by the $file variable in Sublimetext 3 - filepath would look like "${file}" --
SET filepath="C:\xampp\htdocs\test.html" 
SET searchstring="C:\xampp\htdocs\"
SET replacestring="http://localhost/"
SET modifiedpath=%searchstring%=%replacestring%!

-- not sure about this one but it should work as it does for hardcoded sites --
"C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" !modifiedpath!
```

The result that I get from those commands is just the first filepath that I entered opened in the browser.

What am I doing wrong? I could not find any topics on manipulating paths using cmd.
Systems = W7/32bit and W8/64bit same results

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: -- represtened by the $file variable in Sublimetext 3 - filepath would look like "${file}" --
SET "filepath=C:\xampp\htdocs\test.html" 
SET "searchstring=C:\xampp\htdocs\"
SET "replacestring=http://localhost/"
CALL SET "modifiedpath=%%filepath:%searchstring%=%replacestring%%%"
:: Belt-and-braces
SET "modifiedpath=%modifiedpath:\=/%"

:: -- not sure about this one but it should work as it does for hardcoded sites --
ECHO "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" "%modifiedpath%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work - actually `enabledelayeexpansion` isn't needed here.

Not sure about Opera - the quotes around the executable name are required, but the argument, maybe, maybe not. Since I've not got it installed, I just `ECHO`ed it - you'd need to remove the `ECHO` to make it work. As it is, `CMD` will simply show a command line that should invoke Opera.

Comment: This is a very good explanation and a working batch file corrected in regards of my needs. I'll set up a youtube video as soon as I manage to make this work in sublime.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is replacing the entire path with a new path.  If this is always the case you can do this by using the %~ filename manipulation operations.

```dos
@echo off
set FILEPATH=c:\xampp\htdocs\test.html
call :launch "%FILEPATH%"
goto :EOF

:launch
echo "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" "http://localhost/%~nx1"
```

Or if you are supplying the FILEPATH as an argument %1 to the batch file, just

```dos
echo "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" "http://localhost/%~nx1"
```

you can learn more about the filename manipulation options in cmd by running the command

```dos
help for
```

If this is not the case, you aren't doing yourself any favors by trying to SET your search and replace strings. it's much simpler to just put the necessary search and replace text inline.

```dos
@echo off
set FILEPATH=c:\xampp\htdocs\foo\test.html
set NEWPATH=%FILEPATH:c:\xampp\htdocs\=http://localhost/%
echo "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" "%NEWPATH:\=/%"
```

You can learn more about string substitution by running

```dos
help set
```

Comment: Great for understanding what happens behind the scences, I tried to upvote this post, but i have not enough reputations so far, so thanks a lot.